# Find the value of Legendre (12/227)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the value of  Legendre (12/227)?

How does one approach this after decomposing into (4/227)(3/227)? I am stuck after the decomposition.

Comment: Please provide more details. What kind of tools/theorems about Legendre symbols do you know?

Comment: I know about Euler's Criterion and the Quadratic Reciprocity theorem.

Comment: You can compute 4/227 just from the definition. And for 3/227, think about those theorems you mentioned

Comment: I computed 3/227 using quadratic reciprocity, but not sure how to approach 4. I split it up into 2/227 * 2/227, but didn't help...

Comment: What do you think? Is $4$ a square mod $227$ or not?

Comment: I don't think so, but I am having a hard time showing that exists no such x such that x^2 = 4 (mod 227).

Comment: Why are you concentrating on proving that it is not a square? When you have trouble proving something, try to disprove it instead. Maybe you were just confused as to whether the statement was true or not.

Comment: It's not actually needed in this case -- but in general you could use the fact that $(\frac{2}{p}) = (-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$ which is 1 if $p \equiv 1, 7 \pmod{8}$ or -1 if $p\equiv 3, 5 \pmod{8}$.